# A unit circle inscribed in parabola $y=x^2$ has center $(0,5/4)$. Generalize this result to $y=ax^2+bx+c$.

Tags: circles, conic-sections

> A circle with radius $1$ inscribed in the parabola $y = x^2$. If the coordinates of the center of the circle in this case is found to be $(0, 5/4)$. Can you generalize this problem for an arbitrary quadratic $y = ax^2 + bx + c$? If so, propose a mathematically precise generalization and prove it.
>
> (Recall that the equation of a circle or radius $r$ centered at the point $(h,k)$ is given by $(x −h)^2 +(y −k)^2 = r^2$.)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (What have you tried? etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or using techniques with which you are unfamiliar. (Plus, it helps convince people that you  aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) [Edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1260355) to add clarifications; comments are easily overlooked.

Comment: Hint: $y = ax^2 + bx + c \iff Y = X^2$ where $x = ax + \frac{b}{2}$ and $Y = ay + \frac{b^2-4ac}{4}$. Since $(x,y)$ are related to $(X,Y)$ by a scaling of factor $a$ plus some translation, a circle in $(X,Y)$ coordinates is a circle in $(x,y)$ coordinates....

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the equation of the general parabola equation as,

$$y = a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2- \frac{b^2}{4a}+c$$

and let the corresponding equation of the circle

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+(y-m)^2=1$$

The center of the circle is $(-\frac{b}{2a}, m)$ with $m$ to be solved next.  Combine the two equations above to obtain the quadratic equation for $y$,

$$y^2+\left(\frac 1a -2m\right)y + \frac 1a \left(\frac {b^2}{4a} -c\right)+ m^2 -1=0$$

Since the parabola and the circle are tangential to each other, the discriminant of above quadratic equation is zero, which leads to the solution for the general case,

$$m= \frac{1}{4a}(1+4a^2-b^2+4ac)$$

In the special case of $y=x^2$, the center becomes $(-\frac{b}{2a}, m)=(0,\frac 54)$.

Comment: You considered the circle with radius $1$. Should not generalization be for any circle with radius $r$?

Comment: The post may only ask for generalization of the parabola. But, the generalization for any $r$ is along the same line. Thanks for the note.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I saw the general formula of circle at the end... As long as a parabola opens, any circle of any radius should fit it. For example, for $y=x^2$ and $r=10$, using your formula we get: $m=\frac{401}{4}$ and this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bn3pmplucr). So, +1.